# Updating all rows when i only want it to update 1

Tags: php, mysql

So i have this code below, to update rows in a database by the ID on click on a submit button, the code updates the database but it updates all the rows.

I have tried looking on google for a solution but as of yet i can't come up with the right answer.

I would like on click of the submit button just for the one row to be updated in the database instead of all rows, but everything i have tried up to now has failed.

Heres my code:

```
<?php

$whoOwns = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sharesbought` WHERE `for_id` = '" . $getID . "'");
while($getWhoOwns = mysql_fetch_assoc($whoOwns)) {
    $aHowMany       = $getWhoOwns['how_many'];
    $aUsername      = $getWhoOwns['username'];
    $aPercentOwned  = $getWhoOwns['percent_owned'];
    $aPaid          = $getWhoOwns['paid'];
    $aID            = $getWhoOwns['id'];

    echo '
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><center>'. $aUsername .'</center></td>
                <td><center>'. $aHowMany .'</center></td>
                <td><center>'. $aPercentOwned .'%</center></td>
                <td><center><a href="/percentofme/'.$aUsername.'">View Profile</a></center></td>';

    if (isset($_POST['mark_as_paid'])) {
        $updatePaid = mysql_query("UPDATE `sharesbought` SET `paid` = 'Yes' WHERE `id` = '". $aID ."'");

        if ($updatePaid) {
            header('Location: eventdisplay.php?id='. $existingID .'');
        }
    }

    if ($getUser == $user_data['username'] && $aPaid =='No') {
        echo '
        <td><center><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" value="'. $aID .'"><button class="btn-u" name="mark_as_paid">Mark Paid</button></form></center></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>';
    } else {
        echo '<td><center>'. $aPaid .'</center></td></td></tbody>';
    }
} 
?>
```

the variables 
$getUser = the username of the person who created the event 
$user_data['username'] = the username of the person logged in

Thanks in advance for any constructive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause doesn't seem to be restrictive enough. It only restricts the update to rows that have the id=$aId, which appears to be associated with more than one row.  if you have the information as to what share was paid for you could add that to your where clause.

`$updatePaid = mysql_query("UPDATE sharesbought SET paid = 'Yes' WHERE id = '". $aID ."' AND share = '".$share."'");`

that way it would only update the rows where the id and share matched.

I would also suggest using prepared statements [PHP Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)